# Swift 4 - UIRefreshControl on vertical UICollectionView lags

Tags: swift, uirefreshcontrol

For some reason, my pull to refresh is really hard to complete. What I mean by that, is that in order to pull-to-refresh I have to begin from the very top of my collection view and scroll down to the very bottom... sometimes I even have to use a second finger in order to scroll more to make it work!

Here's how I initialise the refresher:

```
private var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()

    refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.requestRefreshContent), for: .valueChanged)

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        schoolPostsCollectionView.refreshControl = refresher
    }
    else {
        schoolPostsCollectionView.addSubview(refresher)
    }

    refresher.beginRefreshing()
}
```

Here's how I call `beginRefreshing()`:

```
private func getContentOfSchool() {
    someBackgroundServerCall() {
        // some code

        ...

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
            self.schoolPostsCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: What do you mean by never fully refreshed? does the function `requestRefreshContent` not get called? Are you calling `refreshed.endRefreshing()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: check my updated question. And yes, I am calling `refresher.endRefreshing()` at some points...

Comment: Why are you add subview in Collectionview.

Comment: @S.D because that's how it works...

Comment: @SotirisKaniras Show full code...

Comment: Can you try with `schoolPostsCollectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true`?

Comment: @Kevinosaurio I did try that but it didn't fixed the issue...

Comment: @SotirisKaniras Can you show the full code? Maybe you call `endRefreshing()` in a wrong place.

Comment: I updated my question providing my code...

Answer (score 0):

try this one....

```
refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Refreshing...", attributes: nil)
    refresher.tintColor = UIColor.black
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.requestRefreshContent), for: .valueChanged)

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        schoolPostsCollectionView.refreshControl = refresher
    } else {
        schoolPostsCollectionView.backgroundView = refresher
    }
```